# Different 3-pin fan header, what type is it?

Tags: motherboard, fan, headers

I'm looking to replace a noisy 80mm fan in a media recording device. Unfortunately, it has a non-standard 3-pin fan header, and I can't figure out what type it is. Maybe it's proprietary, I can't find any info on the motherboard either.

Does anyone recognize this header? I'm hoping an adapter will be available.

The included fan is an ADDA AD0812LN-A76GL 12V/0.12A, but after searching online I'm still unable to find the connector type. The connector reads "JCTC" and "41" (see picture).

[image: Different type of 3-pin header on motherboard of media recording device]

[image: Male connector]

Comment: Very old fan adapter. Maybe carefully solder fan leads to the individual metal plugs?

Comment: do you have the fan that attached to it and what's wrong with it? If its 'just' noisy and its a standard set of voltages and such you might be able to trace the wires, keep the current connector and 'just' splice the connector

Comment: The fan is an ADDA AD0812LN-A76GL 12V/0.12A (added to question). Yeah, it's "just" noisy, it works fine otherwise, but boy is it loud. I'm not comfortable splicing or soldering, but will have to look into that if there are no adapters.

Comment: There's heat shrink with solder in it - which is basically magic for repairs like this. Big Clive has a video on this, and its the right tool if you need to -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unxEdyW8RP8

Comment: what's the colours on the wires on the fan?

Comment: Maybe also include a picture of the male connector on the current fan's side.

Comment: Blue, black and red. I've added a picture of the connector.

Comment: I'm not comfortable splicing or soldering,   ........   Get a friend or local shop to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, I appreciate it. In the end I found a SATA to 3/4-pin adapter that I can use to power the quieter fan instead, and I've suppressed the fan warnings resulting from no fan being attached to the above header now. Still interested in learning the name of the header but problem solved for now.